# YouTube report contains no data rows

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-reporting-api

I have created a job with report type `channel_basic_a1` in the YouTube Reporting API. Over the night 2 reports were generated for this job. However when I download them, they only contain a header row and no data rows. Is this normal behaviour? Is it going to be updated with data when it's becoming available? How do I determine when I can download them again with data?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/):

> If no data is available for the given query, the rows element will be omitted from the response.

It's possible that your query did not return any data, or the data is not available yet.  Try again in a few days to verify that the analytics data is in fact available.  The response for a query with the day dimension will not contain rows for the most recent days.

Comment: My question was about the Reporting API, while you refer to a docs page from the Analytics API. The Analytics API returns non-zero data for the day, that is why I have expected to receive data.

Comment: @PeterMolnar Ah my mistake, I'll keep researching.